# using servlet, how to insert radio button values and check box values into database?

Tags: html, ms-access, servlets

I don't know how to insert gender(radio button), favorite subjects(checkbox) into database using servlet. Here is my coding...

FORM:

```
        <form name="myform" action="NewServlet" method="GET">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
            Age: <input type="text" name="age" value="" />
            Gender: <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="" />Male
                   <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="" />Female
            Your favorite: <input type="checkbox" name="fav" value="" />C
                    <input type="checkbox" name="fav" value="" />C++
                    <input type="checkbox" name="fav" value="" />JAVA
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

NewServlet:

```
        public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet
            {
                public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
                {
                    res.setContentType("text/html");
                    PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
                    Connection conn;
                    Statement stmt;
                    String name=req.getParameter("name");
                    int age=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("age"));
                    try
                    {
                        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mydb");
                        stmt=conn.createStatement();
                        int i=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into student values(' "+name+" ',' "+age+" ') ");
                        if(i>0)
                            out.print("Inserted Successfully");
                        else
                            out.print("Fail to Insert");
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){out.print(e);}
                }}
```

Comment: also i add, value="Male", value="Female", value="C" and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The way radio buttons work is you set the `value` in your HTML code and give them the same `name`. When the form is submitted, the browser only sends the `value` of the one that is selected. So your issue is you left the values blank.

```
  Gender: <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" />Male
          <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female" />Female
```

Once you have the values in there, you just use `req.getParameter("Gender")` like you did with the other parameter.

But 2 tips: (1) Your code is open to SQL injection. (2) You should include a column list in your insert.  If you don't, adding fields to the table schema later will break your insert in the future. I.e. `insert into table (col1, col2) values('val1', 'val2');`

Comment: i also add the value field. how to get check box value using getParameter()

Comment: You're wanting to validate client-side aren't you?  That would be Javascript.